# UIAlert With %@

Tags: uialertview

I am learning Objective - C and I want to replace the %@ in an alert with a word. This is my code:

```
NSString *myString = @"John";
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Welcome:%@", myString message:...
```

Can someone fix the code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[@"Welcome " stringByAppendingString:myString] ...];
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you have `%@` your string it means that some sort of string will replace it anyway

You need to be using the `stringWithFormat:` method for `NSString *` check out the [Apple Documentation for NSString *](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

For you, you just need to do the following

```
 NSString *myString = @"John";
 UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome: %@", myString]
                                                  message:@"Some Message"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
```

You will fine that `%@` in the `stringWithFormat:` will be replaced with your string (`myString`)